# "Infinite" line that passes through two points

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, line

In the following setup, how can I draw an "infinite" line that passes through two points?

```js
var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var point1 = {
    x : 120,
    y : 100,
};

var point2 = {
    x : 250,
    y : 300,
};

// mark points in the canvas
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point1.x + 0.5, point1.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point2.x + 0.5, point2.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();

// draw a line between two points
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
context.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
context.stroke();

// draw an "infinite" line that passes through two points
// ??
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
                0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I know that I need to calculate new coordinates that are on the same path, but are outside of the view (canvas) and draw a line between them to fake an infinite line.

These new coordinates don't necessarily have to be on the edges of the canvas. I think that would require extra calculation. So I'm thinking something like

```
current position ± canvas diagonal (max distance in canvas)
```

just to make sure the new coordiates are always outside of canvas, and skip redundant calculation.

How do I calcutate these new coordinates?

Answer (score 4):

Taking a trip back to algebra class, you can work out your slope and intercept and use that to plot points on the edge of your canvas. If they're out of bounds of the canvas, it will create a line that extends off the edges.

HOWEVER please note that this will not support horizontal or vertical lines, you'll have to add in extra checks to cover those instances. Essentially, if the slope is 0, just draw a line from 0 to canvas.width at the `y` value of the two points, and if it's undefined, draw a line from 0 to canvas.height at the `x` value of the two points.

```js
var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var point1 = {
    x : 120,
    y : 100,
};

var point2 = {
    x : 250,
    y : 300,
};

var slope = (point2.y - point1.y)/(point2.x - point1.x)
//y = mx + b | b = y - mx
var intercept = point2.y - (slope * point2.x)

function getY(x){ return (slope * x) + intercept; }
function getX(y) { return (y - intercept)/slope; }

// mark points in the canvas
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point1.x + 0.5, point1.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point2.x + 0.5, point2.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();

// draw a line between two points
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(getX(0), 0);
context.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
context.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
context.lineTo(getX(context.canvas.height), context.canvas.height);
context.stroke();

// draw an "infinite" line that passes through two points
// ??
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
                0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, specifically on the `get` functions? I'm going to write this into a function (e.g., `line(p1, p2)`), and I want to fully understand what's going on in the calculation. PS: Sadly, my math knowledge lacks some concepts and this seems to be one of them. Can you name a topic about this, so I can look it up online?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand this. There are two fixed parallel lines: top and bottom of the canvas. We calculate new coordinates (x) on these parallel lines and draw a line between them. These new coordinates extend the canvas (get far away from each other) as the line gets closer to being horizontal. They get close as the line becomes vertical. This is clever :)

Comment: Also I've removed unnecessary `lineTo()` from the code. Instead of drawing three lines, I just draw one. Added extra checks for the vertical and horizontal lines. Here's an updated demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/m3ea2kx6/). What I don't understand is you created two `get` functions, but used only `getX()`. Is `getY()` not needed? Or for it to be needed, do I need to use vertical paralel lines (left and right) and calculate `y`, instead of horizontal paralel lines (top and bottom) and calculate `x`? So only one of them is needed depending on what I choose to do?

Comment: @akinuri Yes, you only need one in this case. I just included both for the sake of thoroughness, you can use either approach. Since your original example extended off the top and bottom, I wound up basing it on `getX()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to find two points in which the line crosses with canvas edges:

```js
var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var point1 = {
    x : 120,
    y : 100,
};

var point2 = {
    x : 250,
    y : 300,
};

var a = (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x);
var b = (point1.y * point2.x - point2.y * point1.x) / (point2.x - point1.x);

// mark points in the canvas
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point1.x + 0.5, point1.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(point2.x + 0.5, point2.y + 0.5, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();

// draw a line between two points
//context.beginPath();
//context.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
//context.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
//context.stroke();

// draw an "infinite" line that passes through two points
// ??

var canvasWidth = context.canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = context.canvas.height;

var leftSideY = b;
var rightSideY = (canvasWidth * a) + b;
var topSideX = (-b) / a;
var bottomSideX = (canvasHeight - b) / a;

// vertical line
if ([Infinity, -Infinity].includes(a)) {
  topSideX = bottomSideX = point1.x; 
}
// same points
if (a !== a) {
  throw new Error("point1 and point2 are the same") 
}

const edgePoints = [
  {x: 0, y: leftSideY},
  {x: canvasWidth, y: rightSideY},
  {x: topSideX, y: 0},
  {x: bottomSideX, y: canvasHeight}
  ].filter(({x, y}) => x >= 0 && x <= canvasWidth && y >= 0 && y <= canvasHeight);

context.beginPath();

context.moveTo(edgePoints[0].x , edgePoints[0].y || 0);
context.lineTo(edgePoints[1].x || point2.x, edgePoints[1].y || canvasHeight);
context.stroke();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15),
                0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```